# double format em um toString

Tags: java

Olá, meu problema é o seguinte: O exercício pede para imprimir diversos valores em Reais. Depois dos cálculos de impostos em cima deste valor (feito no objeto) tenho o toString imprimindo os valores, porém ele imprime: 
`msg += "\n\nTotal Impostos: R$" + totalImpostos() + "\nTotal Mercadorias: R$" + totalMercadorias() +
        "\nTotal Geral: R$" + totalGeral;`

Queria que estes valores fossem mostrados em R$ x.xx, no máximo duas casas decimais depois do ponto. Tem essa possibilidade?

O código do exercício foi todo feito por mim, então não tenho a certeza de estar certo ou não.

[image: Como está sendo impresso]

Comment: Mas se é valor monetário porque está usando `double`?

Comment: Eu realmente não sei qual formato é o mais correto, perdi às aulas de tipos primitivos. Deveria usar float ao invés disto?
Oh, irei verificar esta pergunta que você mandou. Obrigado

Comment: Se o formato estiver em double, se o idioma do seu compoutador estiver em Portugues Brasileiro, você pode usar assim: `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format( 2 )`, que ele ja mostra justamente assim: `R$ 2,00`